# SQL Server when is correct to use different instance for performance purpose?

Tags: sql-server

I have two very big and "stressed" databases in a single SQL Server 2008 instance and I experience a sensible slowness in the first database when the second database is under heavy work.

It also appear that the Server RAM are CPU are not really under stress and I have some spare resources that I can use.

I'm planning to buy a second SQL Server machine and move one of the database to separate them but before to do so I would like to understand if creating two differente instances on the same server, with one database each, could solve my issue.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Voted to close : belongs to the [dba site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) of the network

Comment: You mentioned CPU and RAM are not stressed. What about storage? Assuming bare metal, faster storage will be a lot less expensive in terms of both hardware and licensing.

Comment: What is your full @@version? How did you check that there is enough RAM for the serve? You could see that it's enough for your pc, but maybe your SQL Server cannot use all the memory due to edition limitation

Comment: What is "very big" (in terms of total size in GB and approx # of rows in largest tables).  what is the ram and cpu for the server?  also what windows OS?  slowness is often fixed with indexes but sometimes hw too.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no stress on CPU please check the other component for troubleshooting. Also check the database configuration like MAXDop, Cost threshold for parallelism etc.  It doesn't make sense to buy a complete new server without knowing the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience a separate instance on the same server will allow you to control resources allocated to each instance.  You can do that however with other means like resource governor, especially with newer versions of SQL Server.  I have found that creating a new instance is more useful for security and separation of concerns than performance.

I agree with Dans comment.  If you have no issues with RAM / CPU, disk is the next place to look.  I have however seen slow performance with RAM / CPU / DISK / Network all at low usage and the problem was solved with changes to indexing.

If your disk looks good, I suggest checking for blocking and locking issues as well as index tuning.

Comment: Thanks. I have some indexing and locking issue on the first database but what is puzzling me is that why this affect the second database performance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few reasons to use different instances.

1. Different resource configuration
2. Server level settings / installation settings
3. The most important of them all. Sql-Server has only one TempDB, and you can only use so much of it. So if you predict you will get there, then more than 1 instance really makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. TempDB can be a key elements because I have several locking issue on the first database